# All https requests are goes as TLS (windows 7 64bit)

Tags: windows-7, ssl, https, tls

I have installed a version of windows 7 64bit on my laptop. After it all software that are going to send request to https has failed because the OS are using TLS instead of SSL3. I find it because all of my projects (c# .net) that works fine in my previous vista 32bit has failed and needs one code that forced windows to use SSL3 instead of both TLS and SSL3 together. I can visit https urls through browsers but software that needs response from their website (through https links) has failed because their request (i.e. https://example.com/login/) will be change to http:443 (i.e. http://example.com:443). I appreciated any help fix it.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  If your software is unable to connect to through SSL3 then the problem is the code not your Windows installation.  Sounds like you need to look at what references you are using, validate you are using 64-bit versions of the reference when required, and make sure you have all required support software installed.

Comment: @Ramhound, same software was working fine in my previous vista 32bit (about 10 days before installing windows 7 64bit) I'm a 10 years programmer and I know the issue is not from software. The mentioned software are not mine and it's a purchased software. But about my projects, I have hundred projects that was works fine in vista and now they need one line code for working in my windows 7 (not others win7) and that line is a declaration that forced windows to use only SSL3 protocol instead of TLS-SSl3. Thanks

Comment: All I know is that is no reason Windows 7 would have changed anything to do with TLS or SSl3.